# Probability of Convergence of Stochastic Process to $1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

We define the stochastic process $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ with $X_0 = x \in [0, 1]$, and:
\begin{align*}
X_{n+1} = 
\begin{cases}
X_n^2, &\text{ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$} \\
2X_n - X_n^2, &\text{ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I want to show that $\mathrm{P}[\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = 1] = x$. This is a homework problem, and I was given the following hint:

> Use Martingale Convergence Theorem. Under what conditions is the expectation of limit equals that of martingale under what conditions?

---

My attempt involves first showing that $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is indeed a martingale. One can check that $0 \leq X_n \leq 1 \; \forall n$, so we can apply both Martingale Convergence Theorem and Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude that $X_n \to X$ for some random variable $X$, and $\mathrm{E}[X] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathrm{E}[X_n] = x$. I'm stuck on where to proceed here.

I conjecture that $X \in \{0,1\}$ almost surely, which would thus imply the result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you showed that $X_n$ is a martingale.

Comment: First we should show by induction that $X_n\in[0,1]$ for all $n$, then show that $\mathbb E[X_n]<\infty$, and finally that $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid X_n] = X_n$. I am assuming you have already shown this without difficulty?

Comment: Showing that $X_n$ is a martingale here is but simple computation, thus I did no include it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Martingale Convergence Theorem $X =\lim X_n$ exist a.e. Taking limit in the definition we see that  $X=X^{2}$ or $X=2X-X^{2}$. The second equation is same as the first so $X=X^{2}$ a.s. This means $X=0$ or $1$ a.s. Also $P(\lim X_n=1)=P(X=1)$. Since $X$ is $0-1$ valued $EX=P(X=1)$. Hence $P(\lim X_n=1)=EX=EX_0=x$

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that in general, should the limit of a martingale exist, we can evaluate the limit as if they're numerical sequences?

Comment: Just to be certain - the equality $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X_0]$ holds from the general property of martingales having a constant mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @Math1000